# Displaying custom button class in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I've created a custom button class that I wish to add to my layout created using QT Designer.

Here is the first class' **init** function:

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button1 = Button()
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.button1.playSample)
```

And here is the button class it is calling:

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 61, 51))
        self.setText("Drag onto Me")
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to display this button class in the way I display the buttons created by QT Designer.

Buttons are currently added in the setupUi function of the Ui_Form class in the following way (they are not added to a layout manager, so I assume 'form' has something to do with it, however I just do not know what to do!):

```
    self.btn_b8 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
    self.btn_b8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 90, 61, 51))
    self.btn_b8.setText("")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Python/LP_Proj/LP_Square_Off.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.btn_b8.setIcon(icon)
    self.btn_b8.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
    self.btn_b8.setObjectName("btn_b8")
```

Here is a minimalistic example of code (as small as I could make it) that depicts a button working, and the button I am trying to create not being shown.. The reason I don't know how to implement using a layout manager is that I have a background image that needs to be used, and with a layout manager the image just gets put into one of the slots, rather than placing everything upon it. But this is most likely due to my limited knowledge of PyQt!

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(591, 591)
        self.Background = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.Background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 631, 591))
        self.Background.setText("")
        self.Background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Python/LP_Proj/LP_Background.png"))
        self.Background.setObjectName("Background")

        self.btn_a1 = Button(Form)

        self.btn_a2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btn_a2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 41, 41))
        self.btn_a2.setText("")
        self.btn_a2.setObjectName("btn_a2")

        self.lab_a1 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.lab_a1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 76, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lab_a1.setFont(font)
        self.lab_a1.setObjectName("lab_a1")

        self.lab_a2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.lab_a2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 76, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lab_a2.setFont(font)
        self.lab_a2.setObjectName("lab_a2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Launchpad Control", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btn_a1.clicked.connect(self.btn_a1.playSample)
        self.lab_a1.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#ffffff;\">Unassigned</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.lab_a2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#ffffff;\">Unassigned</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, Form):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 41, 41))
        self.setText("")
        self.setObjectName("btn_a1")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(Button, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(Button, self).dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                self.samplepath = str(url.toLocalFile())
                print self.samplepath
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(Button,self).dropEvent(event)

    def playSample(self):
        sample = self.samplepath
        print sample

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The button 'a1' should be created to the left of 'a2' and above the label 'a1'. Below is a small screenshot of the programme running and where the button should be. In all there is a total of 80 buttons + labels, all with this drag and drop functionality, hence why I'd prefer/need to use a class. The class will eventually determine the positioning and image for the button, but for now I'm just trying to get it to work!

[image: Example of button]

Comment: You define `self.button1` in the line above that; you don't define `button1` anywhere. They're not the same thing—one is an instance attribute that exists, the other is a global variable that doesn't.

Comment: Totem just pointed that out: that was an error whilst I was playing around trying to fix things. If I have .connect(self.button1.playSample) the programme runs but seems to completely ignore the instantiation of the class?

Comment: The class is being instantiated; how can it *not* be? What do you expect to be happening that is not?

Comment: The button is just one in a number of buttons. The other buttons have all been created in the setupUi function called in Ui_Form's init. 

I'm attempting to create a class for the buttons to cut down the code from over 1000 lines to about 100.

So in summary, button1 does not appear at all!

Comment: Where's the code where you add the button to your layout?

Comment: I thought I had done with the `self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 61, 51))` line? I assume this should be where I do my research?

Comment: Can you provide a minmilistic example (something we can run) with 2 buttons that work (created by `setupUi`) and the one that doesn't. It is difficult to understand what you are currently doing.

Comment: I've added a working piece of code as small as I could make it that depicts the button creation in both ways :)

I assume that my problem is calling the Button class I create with the Form argument, but I'm not sure where to use it and everything I've tried either creates just a normal QPushButton that doesn't work with my custom button settings or doesn't display anything!

Comment: Full fix posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829043/custom-button-pyqt4/29830530#29830530

Comment: Full fix is posted here!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829043/custom-button-pyqt4/29830530#29830530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not ignoring the instantiation of the `Button` class. Neither is PyQt. The button is definitely being created.

The key is that while it is being created, **you are not able to see it**. This is because you must either add it to a layout which is a child of your `Ui_Form` or explicitly specify the parent widget for the button (the former actually does the latter internally anyway).

I would suggest adding it to a layout in your `Ui_Form` so that it behaves nicely when resizing the window, etc. Have a look in the `setupUi()` method to see how the buttons there are added to a layout. Then replicate this for your custom button.

Comment: I'll add the way that buttons are currently added in the setupUi function into my question due to not being able to properly format it here. 

I don't really understand how to do either of the things you said for my button however, sorry if I'm being stupid and it's incredibly simple!

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem at hand now, however I've no clue how to add the button to my existing layout. I don't use a layout manager, there are 80 buttons all created in the way stated at the bottom of the question. They are never added to a layout manager at all, so how can I display the button I created in this way?

Comment: Creating it with the form as the parent should be enough then, just move() it to where you want it and show() it. But use a layout manager...

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use a layout manager for my purpose because: 
I have a background image, so if I construct the whole thing using a layout manager, the image will just be set as a 'block' within the manager and not as a background? If that makes sense. For example, my background would be top left, a button would be the next square along and so forth