# Custom button PyQT4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I'm having trouble displaying a button that I create from a class in PyQt4, using Python 2.7. My project has 80 buttons that all require a drag and drop function. I've created a button class that allows this, but I'm unsure as to how to display it within `Ui_Form`.

I don't think I can use a layout manager as I want a background image so I assume I need to create the button from the Button class using the `Form` argument from `Ui_Form`'s `setupUi` function, but I'm insure as to how.

Below is an example of the script with only two buttons (and a screenshot)- one called from my class and one just as QT Designer left it. The button `btn_a1` should be visible to the left of `btn_a2`, but it isn't (due to not knowing how to properly call it). I've removed the code for the labels and functionality of the buttons to help with ease of use.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(591, 591)
        self.Background = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.Background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 631, 591))
        self.Background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Python/LP_Proj/LP_Background.png"))
        self.Background.setObjectName("Background")

        self.btn_a1 = Button(Form)

        self.btn_a2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btn_a2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 41, 41))
        self.btn_a2.setObjectName("btn_a2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Launchpad Control", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, Form):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 41, 41))
        self.setObjectName("btn_a1")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Example of button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification is required in your `Button` class:

```
def __init__(self, text='', parent=None):
    super(Button, self).__init__('Text', parent=parent)
    ...
```

Then in your `setupUi` method in `Ui_Form` change

```
self.btn_a1 = Button(Form)
```

to

```
self.btn_a1 = Button('Text', self)
```

The UI now looks like this:

[image: Button UI]

Comment: Many thanks, been stuck on this for hours and don't think I'd have ever thought to do that!